# Listview inside constraintLayout not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

I have a listview inside my ConstraintLayout and I read its supposed to automatically be scrollable, but the list just gets cut-off at the bottom with more items left to be displayed and its not scrollable, I dont know if Im setting some atribute wrong or if I have to add something for listview to scroll??

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/special_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Today is:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="The date is:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/special_text_view"/>



     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oc_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="The day of the omer is:"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_text_view"/>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/zmanim_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/omer_chanukah_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

</ListView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: just try give listview width 0dp and listview start and end constraint.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem where my ListView did not scroll inside a ConstraintLayout. For me, the solution was setting the ListView to **`android:layout_height="0dp"`** with top and bottom constraints.

**Example**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_above_this_one"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    >
</ListView>
```

Comment: his didn't work for me. My case is different though in that I'm adding buttons after the view is created and the view is in a dialog. What finally worked is to put the linear layout in a scroll view (which i've seen in other comments you should not do), set a fixed height for the scroll, 0dp shows nothing and wrap content doesn't scroll). The layout has height set to wrap content. Far from ideal since i have as fixed height but it's in a dialog and at least it works. :( P.S. also tried invalidate view. PSS API = 32

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your entire layout? In what you've actually included, your `TextView` has this attribute:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

which causes none of the views to appear on screen when I run an app with this layout. If I change that to

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

then I see everything working just fine (the ListView doesn't get clipped).

Comment: Hi, I excluded a couple of textviews that were in the middle, what you pointed out was a mistake and I fixed it but Its still not working for me.

Comment: @Jack it's possible the views you've excluded are part of the problem.

Comment: dont think so, but just added the rest just in case.